# regular expression to replace sub pattern 'hello1, 2, 3' with 'hello' without affecting other numbered patterns

Tags: python, regex

Apologies I'm inexperienced with regular expressions

I want to get rid of all the sub-patterns in a string that are characterised by having a number straight after a word ('hello1') and or having a series of numbers after the word ('hello1, 2, 3') and to replace this pattern with just the original word (hello).

Below I have text:

> x='interspersed by 1,6-hexanediol, corresponds to the immobile
>   component observed with FRAP. Consistent with this idea, the immobile
>   fraction of HP 1a.... own to arise through phase separation23. N&B
>   analysis of GFP–fibrillarin highlighted areas of consistently high
>   variance (2.38 ± 0.46 -mers) at the nucleolar boundary, compared to
>   inside (1.28 ± 0.36) or outside (1.17 ± 0.25) the domain24, 25, 26.
>   Similarly, GFP–HP 1a displayed increased variance34, 37'

```
x =re.sub(r'([^ 0-9])(\d+(?:, \d+)*)', r'\1', x)
```

Above I use a regular expression to get rid of the patterns with numbers immediately proceeding a word however it also give un-intended effects:

> interspersed by 1,-hexanediol, corresponds to the immobile component
>   observed with FRAP. Consistent with this idea, the immobile fraction
>   of HP 1a.... own to arise through phase separation. N&B analysis of
>   GFP\xe2\x80\x93fibrillarin highlighted areas of consistently high
>   variance (.\xe2\x80\x89\xc2\xb1\xe2\x80\x89. -mers) at the nucleolar
>   boundary, compared to inside (.\xe2\x80\x89\xc2\xb1\xe2\x80\x89.) or
>   outside (.\xe2\x80\x89\xc2\xb1\xe2\x80\x89.) the domain. Similarly,
>   GFP\xe2\x80\x93HP 1a displayed increased variance

The intended output is:

> x='interspersed by 1,6-hexanediol, corresponds to the immobile
>   component observed with FRAP. Consistent with this idea, the immobile
>   fraction of HP 1a.... own to arise through phase separation. N&B
>   analysis of GFP–fibrillarin highlighted areas of consistently high
>   variance (2.38 ± 0.46 -mers) at the nucleolar boundary, compared to
>   inside (1.28 ± 0.36) or outside (1.17 ± 0.25) the domain.
>   Similarly, GFP–HP 1a displayed increased variance'

patterns such as '1,6-hexanediol', '1.28 ± 0.36' and 'HP 1a' are kept without removing the numbers

UPDATE:

The expression seems to fail to fully get rid of patterns containing a hyphen (e.g. word11-12).

```
x='than allelic variant and define eQTLs9–11'

x = re.sub(r"(?<=\w)\d+(?:, \d+)*", "", x)
```

results in

> than allelic variant and define eQTLs–1

expected output:

> than allelic variant and define eQTLs

can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: If you need to match these numbers after a letter, use a letter matching pattern - [`([a-zA-Z])\d+(?:, \d+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/7najNG/1)

Comment: its your [^ 0-9] character matcher, its matching on the "," inside the "1,6-..." and the "(" and the "." from the "(1.28 +-...".  Either change to `x =re.sub(r'([^ ,\(\)\.0-9])(\d+(?:, \d+)*)', r'\1', x)` or just `x =re.sub(r'([^A-Za-z])(\d+(?:, \d+)*)', r'\1', x)`

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of those little citation marker superscript thingies? It looks like you've already discarded useful metadata with earlier processing, and it would have been easier to identify the citation thingies at an earlier stage.

Comment: What's the expected output from the example containing a hyphen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = re.sub(r"(?<=\w)\d+(?:, \d+)*", "", x)
```

#### Explanation

`(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind. It basically says "make sure this is here, without actually matching it". You could also replace it with a normal group and use `\1` in the replacement, if you wanted.

`\w` matches "word" characters. This is usually equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_]`.

`\d+` matches a number.

`(?:, \d+)*` matches a comma followed by a space followed by a number, zero or more times.

Comment: Is the `?:` necessary, or would regular parentheses work just as well?

Comment: @BallpointBen, a regular group would work fine, but I tend to use non-capturing groups when I don't need to capture things. It reduces clutter in your match result.

Comment: Thanks, was just checking my own understanding

Comment: It's the same reason I used a lookbehind: if this regex were to be used in a different context (ie. to _match_ the numbers instead of delete them), it would work better in this form.

Comment: Hi i am still having a problem see above under UPDATED, thanks